# How to validate the Date format in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, validation, model-view-controller

I have this Validator :

```
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

public class AddActivityValidator  implements Validator{

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {

        return Movement.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object obj, Errors err) {
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(err, "mode_affectation", "modeaffectattion.requiered", "Choisissez un mode d'affectation");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(err, "nom_etabl", "name.required","Choisissez un nom d'une etablissement");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(err, "ville", "city.required","Choisissez une ville");    
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(err, "delegation", "delegation.required","Choisissez une délégation");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(err, "cinn", "cinn.required","Il faut choisir un fonctionnaire au dessus avant d'essayer de saisir un service");

    }

}
```

and I want to validate also the date attribute but the problem is that **ValidationUtils** Class just check if a field is empty. and I don't find any tutorial how to do something to validate the date. Any idea?

* Edit ********

I add this annotation to my attribute in the Class :

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    String date_debut;
```

But how to attach a message to this and link it with the controller ?

Comment: what date validations you want to implement? Is empty or anything else?

Comment: validate the formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to enable Hibernate validation JSR303 with Spring MVC.

```
@Future
@Past
```

[Link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-jsr303-valid-example/)

Comment: What are the steps i must to do? **Future** and **Past** check if the date is in the future or in the past. me I want to check if the user insert the right format or an ordinary string

Comment: for more info about annotations of validation check this link http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html_single/#validator-defineconstraints-builtin

Comment: I edit my post could you check it please. I get this annotation : @DateTimeFotmat